# How to dynamically populate an HTML Table with XML Data?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I have an XML like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestRun id="abc-jhhg-yuh" name="Demo" runUser="Admin" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
 <ResultSummary outcome="Failed">
    <Counters total="5" executed="5" passed="3" failed="2" error="0" timeout="0" aborted="0" inconclusive="0" passedButRunAborted="0" notRunnable="0" notExecuted="0" disconnected="0" warning="0" completed="0" inProgress="0" pending="0" />
  </ResultSummary>
</TestRun>
```

I have an HTML file, where I want this data to be populated dynamically in a tabular format something like below.

[image]

My "script" in HTML goes like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1> Test Summary Details </h1> 
<script>
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","Demo.xml",true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
document.write("<table border='1' width='25%' style='font-size:15px;'>");
document.write("<tr><th>Result Type</th><th>Count</th></tr>");
var nodes=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ResultSummary");
var total= nodes[0].childNodes[0].getAttributeValue("total");
document.write("total");
document.write("</td><td>");
document.write(total);
document.write("</td><td>");
document.write("</table>");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I am not able to populate the data. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Simulate a http response
const mock_response = new Response(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestRun id="abc-jhhg-yuh" name="Demo" runUser="Admin" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
 <ResultSummary outcome="Failed">
    <Counters total="5" executed="5" passed="3" failed="2" error="0" timeout="0" aborted="0" inconclusive="0" passedButRunAborted="0" notRunnable="0" notExecuted="0" disconnected="0" warning="0" completed="0" inProgress="0" pending="0" />
  </ResultSummary>
</TestRun>`)

// use the new fetch api instead of the old XMLHttpRequest
// TODO: change url to 'Demo.xml'
fetch('https://httpbin.org/get').then(async response => {
  // use the simulated response
  const str = await mock_response.text()

  // TODO: remove above and switch to use the actual response.text() instead
  // const str = await response.text() 

  const xml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/xml')
  const counters = xml.querySelector('Counters')
  
  const table = document.createElement('table')
  table.border = 1
  const body = table.createTBody()
  for (let x of 'total,executed,passed,failed,inconclusive,warning,notExecuted'.split(',')) {
    const row = body.insertRow()
    const attr = row.insertCell()
    const value = row.insertCell()
    attr.innerText = x
    value.innerText = counters.getAttribute(x)
    console.log()
  }
  document.body.append(table)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The above code works fine for static xml but the values (total,executed,passed,failed,inconclusive,warning,notExecuted) in XML changes for me. So is there any way to read the XML dynamically while you are simulating the http response.

Comment: change `const str = isDemo ? await res.text() : await response.text()` to just `const str = await response.text()` and also change `https://httpbin.org/get` to your own url `Demo.xml`

Comment: Thanks. Shall I do 
fetch('C:\Users\Downloads\Demo.xml')?  Like this I was not able to get the value. I used fetch('Demo.xml') as well. But is didn't work. Am I missing anything?

Comment: You would have to put up a server to respond with the file. Browser don't have any access to clients filesystem (unless you request permission for it using the new experimental native file system access) Then you are not even using ajax (XMLHttpRequest or fetch api) any more then you are reading a local file instead

Comment: Yes, I want to read a local XML file then populate the data in HTML. Is it possible?

Comment: lets chat instead: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124918/readxml

Comment: I have pinged you in the chat.